# How to force wifi card to connect to an specific Access Point (by MAC)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point

My problem is this, I have access to a network by WIFI that has several access points, then my computer dinamically keeps jumping from one to another (but just one of this works for my pc). 
Using this command (Linux):
`nmcli -f in-use,ssid,bssid,signal,bars  dev wifi` I got this info:
[List of available AP (YACHAYTECH)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDC3I.png)

Then what I want to do is to always connect to an specific AP (in this case the one with MAC FC:EC:DA:A1:50:83) just ignoring the rest. I found this command: nmcli d wifi connect FC:EC:DA:A1:50:83, it allows me to connect for some short time (3 - 10 minutes) but later the computer automatically connects to a different AP losing connection.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

UPDATE: According to comments here is the desired info:
`nmcli con`:  [nmcli con](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Asxma.png)

And my version of linux is Ubuntu 18.04.2  Kernel version: 4.15.0-46-generic

And my network card is:

```
 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
```

Comment: Can you check how many profiles for this ESSID you have in `nmcli con`? (Older NM versions would generate a new one every time.)

Comment: What's the version of Linux? What's the make model of the wireless card/adapter? Please update your **question** with this information, not the **comments** section.

Comment: I have added the information you asked for.